# ¿Cómo puedo limitar las entradas de datos en un Bucle? Python

Tags: python, array, bucle-for, while

Estoy aprendiendo a programar y tengo una asignación que me pide que declare un vector de diez elementos enteros y pida números para rellenarlo hasta que se llene el vector o se introduzca un número negativo.

Tengo el siguiente código pero al completar 10 valores no se cierra el ciclo y continua.

¿Alguna sugerencia?

```
from array import *

lista = array('i',[])

print("Este programa aceptará 10 elementos digitados por el usuario.")
print("------------------------------------------------------------")
print("\nEl programa se completará al digitar 10 números o si el usuario digita un número negativo.")
print("------------------------------------------------------------")

numero = int(input("Introduce un número en el vector:"))

while numero>=0:
    for i in range(0,9):
        lista.append(numero)
        numero = int(input("Introduce el siguiente valor:"))
        break

print("El vector generado por los números digitados es de: ",lista)'''
```

Comment: No necesitas del `while`, basta con el `for` y colocar una condición `if numero<0: break`

Answer (score 0):

El núcleo de la solución es:

```
lista = []
while len(lista) < 10:
    numero = int(input("Introduce un número en el vector:"))
    if numero < 0:
        break
    else:
        lista.append(numero)
```

Esto es un patrón común cuando tienes que llenar una lista hasta que se cumplan una o más condiciones:

1. Inicializas la lista vacía.
2. En cada iteración pides un número.
3. Verificas si es negativo, entonces terminas con `break`.
4. Si no es negativo, lo incorporas a la lista y vas a la siguiente iteración.
5. Si la lista ya tiene 10 elementos, es hora de terminar.

#### Demo

```
print("Este programa aceptará 10 elementos digitados por el usuario.")
print("------------------------------------------------------------")
print("\nEl programa se completará al digitar 10 números o si el usuario digita un número negativo.")
print("------------------------------------------------------------")

lista = []
while len(lista) < 10:
    numero = int(input("Introduce un número en el vector:"))
    if numero < 0:
        break
    else:
        lista.append(numero)

print("El vector generado por los números digitados es de: ",lista)
```

produce:

```
Este programa aceptará 10 elementos digitados por el usuario.
------------------------------------------------------------

El programa se completará al digitar 10 números o si el usuario digita un número negativo.
------------------------------------------------------------
Introduce un número en el vector:4
Introduce un número en el vector:7
Introduce un número en el vector:6
Introduce un número en el vector:3
Introduce un número en el vector:-1
El vector generado por los números digitados es de:  [4, 7, 6, 3]

Process finished with exit code 0
```